restar unos días a fechas en el calculo
Espero me puedan ayudar.. en este script el cálculo de las fechas lo hace muy bien, al poner por ejemplo 3 meses e ingresar la fecha de Ingreso, se hace el cálculo de la fecha final y la de Fecha Preaviso pero me gustaría hacerle un par de modificaciones..

A la fecha final restarle un -1 día
A la fecha Preavisó que aparece restarle - 3 días

acá pongo el codigo... de verdad no se donde poner para que eso se haga así...


const imeses = document.getElementById('duracion');
const ifechainicial = document.getElementById('fechainicial');
const ifechafinal = document.getElementById('fechafinal');
const ifpreaviso = document.getElementById('fechapreaviso');

function calcularFin() {
  let meses = imeses.valueAsNumber;
  let fechaini = ifechainicial.valueAsDate;
  let fechafin = new Date(fechaini.setUTCMonth(fechaini.getUTCMonth() + meses));

  fechafinal.valueAsDate = fechafin;
  const menosUnmes = new Date(fechafin.setUTCMonth(fechafin.getMonth() - 1));
  ifpreaviso.valueAsDate = new Date(menosUnmes.setUTCDate(menosUnmes.getUTCDate() - 10));
}
calcularFin();
<table width="620" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="178" height="32"><span class="texy">Duración:</span></td>
    <td width="442"><input name="duracion" type="number" id="duracion" value="" size="5" style="width:40px" autocomplete="off" class="validar" onChange="calcularFin()" required onKeyPress="nextFocus('duracion', 'fechainicial')">
      <input name="duracion2" type="text" id="duracion2" value="MESES" size="12" class="validar" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="32"><span class="texy">Fecha Ingreso:</span></td>
    <td><input style="width: 120px;" name="fechainicial" type="date" id="fechainicial" size="60" max="9999-12-31" class="validar" onChange="calcularFin()" onKeyPress="nextFocus('fechainicial', 'fechafinal')" required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="32"><span class="texy">Fecha Final:</span></td>
    <td><input style="width: 120px;" name="fechafinal" max="9999-12-31" type="date" id="fechafinal" value="" size="40" class="validar" required onkeypress="nextFocus('fechafinal', 'userfile')"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="32"><span class="texy">Fecha Preaviso:</span></td>
    <td><input style="width: 120px;" max="9999-12-31" name="fechapreaviso" type="date" id="fechapreaviso" size="40" onkeypress="nextFocus('fechapreaviso', 'archivopreaviso')"></td>
  </tr>
</table>



tengo otra duda.. le puse un checkbox al lado de la casilla preaviso la cual borra el contenido del mismo al ser selccionado, pero me gustaria que al quitarlo vuelva la misma fecha que estaba.. pero no me resulta... estoy invocando la constante ifpreaviso que es la que tiene el valor de la fecha pero no me sale al quitar el chek de la casilla
<input style="width: 120px;" max="9999-12-31" name="fechapreaviso" type="date" id="fechapreaviso" size="40" onkeypress="nextFocus('fechapreaviso', 'archivopreaviso')"> 
            <span class="texy">Sin Preaviso:
              <input name="sinpreaviso" type="checkbox" id="sinpreaviso2" value="SI">
      

$("#sinpreaviso2").change( function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
     $('#fechapreaviso').val('');
  } else {
      $('#fechapreaviso').val(ifpreaviso);
  }
});


¿Qué te impide restarle la cantidad de días que mencionás a los resultados que comentás que ya están funcionando?

tienes la opcion de ajustar la funcion calcularFin de esta manera:
const imeses = document.getElementById('duracion');
const ifechainicial = document.getElementById('fechainicial');
const ifechafinal = document.getElementById('fechafinal');
const ifpreaviso = document.getElementById('fechapreaviso');

function calcularFin() {
  let meses = imeses.valueAsNumber;
  let fechaini = ifechainicial.valueAsDate;
  
  // sumando los meses
  let fechafin = new Date(fechaini);
  fechafin.setUTCMonth(fechafin.getUTCMonth() + meses);
  
  // - 1 dia a la fecha final
  fechafin.setUTCDate(fechafin.getUTCDate() - 1);
  fechafinal.valueAsDate = fechafin;
  
  // preaviso restando un mes
  let preaviso = new Date(fechafin);
  preaviso.setUTCMonth(preaviso.getMonth() - 1);
  
  // -3 dias a la fecha de preaviso
  preaviso.setUTCDate(preaviso.getUTCDate() - 3);
  ifpreaviso.valueAsDate = preaviso;
}

calcularFin();

cuando calcula la fecha final se usa fechafin.setUTCDate(fechafin.getUTCDate() - 1) para restarle un dia y para los 3 dias a la fecha de preaviso al calcular se usa preaviso.setUTCDate(preaviso.getUTCDate() - 3) para ejecutar -3
aver dale !!

Mil gracias por tu respuesta la fecha Inicial y final lo hacen bien pero la fecha del Preaviso debería ser 1 meses, y 12 días a la fecha final.... por lo que le puse -12 Mil gracias!!! alli me habia confundido un poco

puse al final un extracto de algo pues es del mismo tema para no abrir otro hilo y no saber expresarme para lo que deseo.. mil gracias por ayudarme
